# Скорость отклика сервера

Tags: сервер

Зависит ли скорость отклика сервера от скорости интернета провайдера к которому подключен сервер?

Answer (score 1):

В основном от пинга между сервисом и клиентом, и от нагрузки на сервер

Answer (score 1):

Конечно зависит, опредоставляемых услугах вы можете уточнить у провайдера. Вы также можете проверить скорость самостоятельно написав приложение, которое раздает файлы больших размеров или испольльзовать уже готовое. Вы сразу же определите, что скорость ограничена.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит: выше скорость быстрее отклик (задержка/latency).
Также зависит еще от многих факторов, например от расстояния между хостами.

Утилита покажет задержку текущих соединений на ПК:

[NetworkLatencyView v1.61 Copyright (c) 2013 - 2018 Nir Sofer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_latency_view.html)

P.S.

1. [Latency on a Switched Ethernet Network](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/94772587/how-do-you-calculate-the-latency-on-a-switched-ethernet-network-with-ruggedcom-switches-or-routers-?dti=0&lc=en-WW) ([.pdf файл](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/587/94772587/att_113195/v1/94772587_ruggedcom_latency_switched_network_en.pdf))
2. [What is network latency and how does it affect you?](http://smutz.us/techtips/NetworkLatency.html)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [How much network latency is “typical” for east - west coast USA?](https://serverfault.com/questions/137348/how-much-network-latency-is-typical-for-east-west-coast-usa)